# Creating a 2d NumPy array (Python)

Tags: python, numpy

NumPy newb.

I created a simple 2d array in **np_2d**, below. Works great.

Of course, I'm generally going to need to create N-d arrays by appending and/or concatenating existing arrays, so I'm trying that next.

The np.append method (with or without the axis parameter) doesn't seem to do anything.

My attempts to use .concantenate() and/or simply replace raw lists with np arrays also fail.

I'm sure this is trivial to do...just not trivial for me ATM. Can someone push me in the right direction? TY.

```
import numpy as np

# NumPy 2d array:
np_2d = np.array([[1.73, 1.68, 1.71, 1.89, 1.79], [65.4, 59.2, 63.6, 88.4, 68.7]])

print (np_2d) 

# [[ 1.73  1.68  1.71  1.89  1.79]
# [65.4  59.2  63.6  88.4  68.7 ]]

print (np_2d[1]) # second list

# [65.4 59.2 63.6 88.4 68.7]

np_2d_again = np.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3])

np.append(np_2d_again, [4.4, 5.5, 6.6])
print(np_2d_again)

# wrong: [1.1 2.2 3.3], expect [1.1 2.2 3.3], [4.4, 5.5, 6.6]
# or MAYBE [1.1 2.2 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6]


np_2d_again = np.array([[1.1, 2.2, 3.3]])
np.concatenate(np_2d_again, np.array([4.4, 5.5, 6.6]))

# Nope: TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

print(np_2d_again)

np_height = np.array([1.73, 1.68, 1.71, 1.89, 1.79])
np_weight = np.array([65.4, 59.2, 63.6, 88.4, 68.7])

np2_2d_again = np.array(np_height, np_weight)

# Nope: TypeError: data type not understood

height = [1.73, 1.68, 1.71, 1.89, 1.79]
weight = [65.4, 59.2, 63.6, 88.4, 68.7]

np2_2d_again = np.array(height, weight)

# Nope: TypeError: data type not understood
```

Comment: Use `A = np.append(B, C)`, the append function returns and array and does not change the arguments.
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html

Comment: `np.concatenate`: "The arrays must have the same shape" https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html (can't concatenate 2D and 1D arrays in your case).

Comment: Stay away from `np.append`; it's too easy to misuse.  When using `np.concatenate` pay close attention to array shapes.  If doing this repeatedly, it is better to collect a list, and do one `concatenate` (or `stack`) at the end.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with the last bit (the height, weight)?

Comment: Thanks all. @Nathan Nothing, really. Those two lists could be used to calculate BMI in the "end game", but I really was just trying to figure out how stuff behaves (curiosity) vs. trying to solve an actual problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For questions like these, the docs can be really useful. Check them out here:

- [numpy.append](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html)
- [numpy.concatenate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html?highlight=numpy%20concatenate#numpy.concatenate)

Using these you'll find:

```
In [2]: np_2d = np.array([[1.73, 1.68, 1.71, 1.89, 1.79], [65.4, 59.2, 63.6, 88.4, 68.7]])
   ...: 
In [2]: np_2d
Out[2]: 
array([[ 1.73,  1.68,  1.71,  1.89,  1.79],
       [65.4 , 59.2 , 63.6 , 88.4 , 68.7 ]])
```

Pay attention to the input to `np.array`.  It is one list, containing 2 lists of equal length.

```
In [3]: np_2d_again = np.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3])
In [4]: np.append(np_2d_again, [4.4, 5.5, 6.6])
Out[4]: array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6])
```

Look at the `np.append` docs.  See what says about raveling?  It is joining one (3,) array to another, the result is (6,).

`np.append` is poorly named and often misused.  It is not a drop in substitute for list append.  For one thing it does not operate inplace.

In your `np.concatenate(np_2d_again, np.array([4.4, 5.5, 6.6]))`, you get error because it expects an axis number as the 2nd argument.  Reread the docs.  You need to give a list of the arrays you want to join.  `np.append` may have misled.

The correct way to use `concatenate`:

```
In [6]: np.concatenate([np_2d_again, np.array([4.4, 5.5, 6.6])])
Out[6]: array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6])
```

But since both inputs are (3,), they can only be joined on the 0 axis, making a (6,) shape.

`np2_2d_again = np.array(np_height, np_weight)` has a similar problem.  The 2nd argument is supposed to be a dtype, not another array.  You used `np.array` correctly the first time.

```
In [7]: np.array([np_2d_again, np.array([4.4, 5.5, 6.6])])
Out[7]: 
array([[1.1, 2.2, 3.3],
       [4.4, 5.5, 6.6]])
```

`np.array` joins the components along a new axis.  It's treating the list of arrays in basically the same as your original list of lists.

`np.stack` is a useful frontend for `concatenate`, which behaves like `np.array` (with a little more flexibility in the use of axis):

```
In [8]: np.stack([np_2d_again, np.array([4.4, 5.5, 6.6])])
Out[8]: 
array([[1.1, 2.2, 3.3],
       [4.4, 5.5, 6.6]])
```